# /show include equivalent option in g++

Tags: visual-c++, g++, gnu

I see that VC++ includes an option called /show include to list you the hierarchy of include files in each translation unit. This seems to be a very helpful option - to optimise/improve the compilation time in a large scale project.

**Question**
Is there any equivalent option in GNU g++ compiler to get these (similar output)?

Comment: See (for GCC 11.2.0) the command line options manual — https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/#toc-GCC-Command-Options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a variety of options for controlling this.

-MD will list files, -MMD will list non-system files as side effects of compilation

-M, -MM will generate lists instead of compiling.

-MQ, -MG, -MP and -MT generate makefile target fragments. -MF allows you to specify an output filename.

Answer (score 16):

```
gcc -H
```

will print the names of header files as they are used.