# C Language: Dependency error while compiling

Tags: build-dependencies

Am facing a problem in resolving dependencies in C,

config.h file is as follows,

```
...
....
/* MACRO */
/* #undef MACRO */
....
....
```

And a file example.c contains,

```
...
     #ifdef MACRO 
     #include "../../sample_header.h"
     #endif
...
```

while resolving dependencies, the compiler is trying to resolve the sample_header.h file even though the "MACRO" is not enabled. Its very weird. Could anyone help on this issue.

Comment: Where is `MACRO` defined? Are you sure it is included from `example.c`? With GCC, use `-MMD` to debug includes ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479049/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The problem i forgot to do "autoreconf" after making changes in configure.ac file. So whenever any change is done in configure.ac "autoreconf" has to be done.